# How to fix ca md too weak vpnbook?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, openconnect

I wanted to connect to freevpn openvpn service so I've followed the setup steps as their [website](https://www.vpnbook.com/howto/) said. but there is a problem about certificate I think.
I've tried:

```
openvpn --config vpnbook-pl226-tcp443.ovpn
```

And here is the error:

```
2022-10-04 16:32:13 OpenSSL: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak
2022-10-04 16:32:13 Cannot load inline certificate file
2022-10-04 16:32:13 Exiting due to fatal error
```

any ideas to fix this error??

Answer (score -2):

The same problem tried downgrade openvpn (no result, because kali didn't see old versions, also if you deleted openvpn for example 2.5.7 version, after install openvpn 2.4.7, kali start thinking that openvpn doesn't exist, I don't know why, I'd try different ways from https://openvpn.net/community-resources/installing-openvpn/), also like you used vpnbook vpns. Maybe somebody knows how to fix this.

P.S. Tried different vpn not vpnbook. And that's work. I'm thinking that versions of vpnbook and openvpn/openssl raise certificate problem.